# Execute antrun maven plugin after allure report

Tags: maven

To execute my test and generate allure report, I run the command line: `mvn clean test allure:report`.

I want to add antrun plugin to do some tasks like copying files... and it should run after allure:report.

I cannot change the command line because it is hard set in CI/CD. If I set `site` phase for antrun, the antrun won't be executed. If I set `test` phase for it, it will run before allure:report because allure:report has `site` phase.

If I set `test` phase for both allure-maven and antrun, it will be like test > allure:report > antrun > allure:report.

Is there any way to achieve my plugin order: test > allure:report > antrun